# Meaning of vector calc identity

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $(\textbf{a}\times\nabla)\cdot\textbf{b}=-\nabla\cdot(\textbf{a}\times\textbf{b})+\textbf{b}\cdot(\nabla\times\textbf{a})$ using the levi civita symbol, but what does $(\textbf{a}\times\nabla)\cdot\textbf{b}$ even mean in general?
If $\textbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is $(\textbf{a}\times\nabla)_1=a_2\partial_3-a_3\partial_2$ (and so on for other components). When you dot this with $\textbf{b} = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ do you get (for component 1) $(a_2\frac{\partial b_1}{\partial x_3}-a_3\frac{\partial b_1}{\partial x_2})$?

Comment: Quite impressive mathjax for a "new user"!

Comment: How can you prove the identity, when you don't even know what $(\textbf{a}\times\nabla)\cdot\textbf{b}$ even means?

Comment: @amWhy I think 11Elves asked the meaning of the formula (why would you ever use such thing). Is there maybe a physical significance of such an expression? He/she knows to apply the steps to prove it, but it would be just a mechanical process, without any meaning.

Comment: I want to prove it, but first i need to know what the left side means. Its not a curl, but something strange. Help

Comment: @Andrei At least, that identity is involved in "Energy Conservation" in "Classical Elegtromagnetism". However, I guess there's something wrong with your post. [See this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.6.E26).

Comment: [It must be](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.6.E26) $\displaystyle\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{b} = -\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}\right) + \mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin $(\mathbf{a}\times \nabla) \cdot \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{b})$ so the OP's formula is also correct.

Comment: @Kusma Thanks $\left(\bullet\qquad\bullet \atop {\mid \atop \smile}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{a}\times \nabla$ is indeed the operator $(a_2 \partial_3-a_3\partial_2, a_3\partial_1 -a_1\partial_3, a_1\partial_2-a_3\partial_2)$. Taking the dot product with $\mathbf{b}$ gives $(\mathbf{a}\times \nabla)\cdot \mathbf{b}=a_2\partial_3 b_1-a_3\partial_2 b_1 + a_3\partial_1 b_2-a_1\partial_3 b_2 + a_1\partial_2 b_3 - a_2\partial_1 b_3$. However, we can also write this as 
$a_1(\partial_2 b_3-\partial_3 b_2)+a_2(\partial_3b_1-\partial_1b_3)+a_3(\partial_1 b_2-\partial_2 b_1)=\mathbf{a}\cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{b})$, which leads you to the formula mentioned by Felix Marin above.